# MultiLine Graphics using Jqplot with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, jqplot

I´m trying to use jqPlot with no problems with ajax using the DataRender command.
My ajax return something like

> [[0,0,53,53,0,0],[78,99,83,58,0,0],[91,99,83,0,0,0],[0,0,45,56,0,0],[0,0,0,50,0,0]]

if I put it manually it works fine but I cannot make it work using ajax

Here is my code

```
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
  var ret = [];
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",async: false,
      url: "modulos/stat.vis.php",
      data: "q="+idStat+"&dde="+$("#statDesde").val()+"&hta="+$("#statHasta").val(),
   dataType:"json",
    success: function(data) {
     ret = [data];
     return data;
    }
  });
  return ret;
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your success callback, you don't return data.

Try this :

```
var ajaxDataRenderer = function(url, plot, options) {
  var ret = [];
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false,
      url: "modulos/stat.vis.php",
      data: "q="+idStat+"&dde="+$("#statDesde").val()+"&hta="+$("#statHasta").val(),
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
         ret = data; // I asume that your data are correctly formatted 
      }
  });

  return ret;
};
```